# How to specify custom-addon directory in Odoo 13?

Tags: ubuntu, odoo-13

I'm following the book  for self learning. And I came to this step

> To add the new addons directory to the Odoo server addons path, change the current directory, and start the server with the appropriate addons path configuration:

This is what I entered into the Ubuntu Terminal:

```
$ cd ~/odoo-dev
$ ./odoo/odoo-bin -d todo --addons-path="custom-addons,odoo/addons" --save
```

However, it returns this error:

> odoo-bin: error: option --addons-path: the path 'custom-addons' is not a valid addons directory

Things I have tried:
I'm sure that I created the **directory** "custom-addons" in ~/odoo-dev
The screenshot below is my current Ubuntu directory structure:
[image: Directory custom-addons]

My software version:
Odoo version 13;

Ubuntu 19

Comment: Try with this syntax: `--add-ons-path=`

Comment: @armoschiano still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what is wrong, we actually have to store a working module in the directory before run the command.

Comment: will you please explain how to store a working module?